# Intellij IDEA can't import two gradle projects containing submodules with the same name

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have two gradle project:

- projectA

  - submodule
- projectB

  - submodule

Both submodules have the same name (but other group id). When I try to import both project to same workspace in IDEA, it imports one project correctly (root module + submodule) and only root module of second project. When I try to manually import missing submodule, it don't allow to it. because: **"module "submodule" already exists in the project"**.

Is this a bug in IDEA ?

Is there any way to import this correctly?

I workaround this by change IDEA project name of "submodule" to "A-submodule", but I suppose that it must be a better way to do it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any idea how to fix it without actually renaming it? I my case everything is already imported but Idea doesn't see the second submodule.

Comment: I am not aware of  any. Probably I ask on IJ forum or report a bug.