# IntelliJ confusion when opening 2 Gradle projects with same module names

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I see [this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232460/intellij-idea-cant-import-two-gradle-projects-containing-submodules-with-the-sa) but got no response and can't find anything on Google...

Using **IntelliJ 15** and Gradle:

I have two projects of the same structure; both have a *domain* and *integration* module. When I do the following:

1. Open the directory containing both Gradle projects in IntellIJ
2. *'Create module from existing sources'* and select **project-a**

   IntelliJ happily recognises all submodules as sources and turns them bold in the project tree view.
3. Perform step 2, this time for **project-b**

Then everything goes wrong. The modules that share the same name (*domain* and *integration*) are removed as project sources from **project-a** (and no longer appear bold in the project tree)

How can I get all modules into a single IntelliJ project? Is there something wrong with my Gradle setup?

I have ensured `group` names are different for submodules if that makes a difference.

Comment: For clarification, is it that **project-a** and **project-b** have the same name, or that *submodule(s)* of both projects have the same name(s)?

Comment: They have the same submodule names :)

Comment: Show your gradle setup and maybe a text diagram of your directory layout please.